# XCOPY /Y "$(BuiltOuputPath)" "\\LOCALHOST\_INSTALL" - what is \\LOCALHOST?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, localhost

I am trying to build a solution that fails with the PostBuildEvent:

> XCOPY /Y "$(BuiltOuputPath)" "\LOCALHOST_INSTALL"

It gives the error:

> Starting post-build events...
>
> Invalid drive specification
>
> 0 File(s) copied

I can access \LOCALHOST but it's empty and I can't create the folder _INSTALL. Is \LOCALHOST some kind of local network folder or how is it used?

Comment: Localhost is your computer on the network. Same as 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Nobody has yet pointed out the syntactical errors with your code above... there should be 2 slashes before `LOCALHOST` (not one), and there should also be a slash between `LOCALHOST` and `_INSTALL`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is a copy/paste error. I've checked and it's correct in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\Localhost` is the name of your machine.  `_INSTALL` would be a share located on your machine.

You would need to share a folder out and give it the share name of `_INSTALL` ensuring you apply the relevant permissions to the share.

Answer (score 1):

Localhost is the network name of your local machine :)

Comment: Yes. I figured:-) I changed the output directory to the hard drive. Now it builds smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` is the name of your local PC.

`\\localhost\_install` refers to a share on your local PC called `_install`.